# C++ Calling function that has template which has inheritance

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance

So I have a class that defines a TileGrid:

```
template<typename T>
class TileGrid { ... };
```

I fill in the template with a class called `ImageTile`

```
class ImageTile { ... };
```

I have a child class of `ImageTile` that I have defined that looks like this:

```
class FFTWImageTile : public ImageTile { ... };
```

In a separate file I define the following function:

```
void writeDataToFile(TileGrid<ImageStitching::ImageTile> * grid, std::string fileName);
```

(note: both `ImageTile` and `FFTWImageTile` are in the ImageStitching namespace)

Now all of the above compiles just fine, but when I try to use it I get an error.

Here is an example test case that is using it:

```
namespace is = ImageStitching;
TileGrid<is::FFTWImageTile> * grid = new TileGrid<is::FFTWImageTile> ( ... );
writeTranslationsToFile(grid, "output.txt");
```

When compiling the test case I get the following error:

`error: cannot convert ‘TileGrid<ImageStitching::FFTWImageTile>*’ to ‘TileGrid<ImageStitching::ImageTile>*’ for argument ‘1’ to ‘void writeTranslationsToFile(TileGrid<ImageStitching::ImageTile>*, std::string)’`

Anyway I can make this happen in C++?? I've looked all over and cant seem to find some help with making a function that has a parameter featuring a template that has child/parent relationships.

Edit:

Everyone's answers have been exceptional and each solve the issue presented. I think decided to move to C++11 and use an assert for this particular case. In the future I think I will add a template to the function and ensure to get the data that way. Thank you all for the help! I have marked what I think is the best answer although each have been acceptable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting the error because despite that `FFTWImageTile` is derived from `ImageTile`, `TileGrid<FFTWImageTile>` and `TileGrid<ImageTile>` are absolutely unrelated classes.

How to fix this depends on the implementation of the classes which you haven't shown. Perhaps you can make `writeDataToFile()` templated:

```
template<typename T>
void writeDataToFile(TileGrid<T> * grid, std::string fileName);
```

Comment: Unfortunately I need specific attributes that are obtainable from the ImageTile class. If I could infer that typename T will be some type of ImageTile, then I think I could add writeDataToFile inside of TileGrid.  For example in java <T extends ImageTile>

Comment: @Jameshobbs you don't have to infer it, just assume it in the code, and if you pass something that is not `ImageTile`, it just won't compile.

Comment: @Jameshobbs and also, if you need `ImageTile` itself, why not pass it to `writeDataToFile`?

Comment: The TileGrid holds an array of T, so I ask the TileGrid to give me an element at a particular row, col index. So the main idea behind writeDataToFile is to output the grid's data, which comprise of northern and western data relative to the origin tile.

Answer (score 0):

You generate two different classes with

```
TileGrid<ImageStitching::ImageTile>
```

and

```
TileGrid<is::FFTWImageTile>
```

They have no relation other than being generated from the same template.  You would want to derive from the class `TileGrid<ImageStitching::ImageTile>` to have an actual subclass for type purposes.

You could templatize the function `writeDataToFile`, but to enforce type restrictions on template arguments, you should use something like...

```
static_assert(is_base_of<T, ImageStitching::ImageTile>>(), "T is not a base of ImageTile");
```

- [static_assert](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static_assert)
- [is_base_of](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_base_of)

Comment: Unfortunately for me is_base_of is a C++11 standard. What is the status of C++11, is it a good idea to enable support?

Comment: You should definitely use C++11/14 if you can.  Compiler support for 11 is fairly comprehensive (VS might still be missing a few things, GCC and Clang are generally feature complete).  I also write Java, and you'll probably be a bit more comfortable using C++11.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Yet another thing I can bring up to my boss as to why we should switch to C++11/14 :D.

Comment: Pre-C++11 doesn't even have a standardized memory model, or hash map (`std::unordered_map`), or a ton of other basic things.  At very least, you may want to take a look at [boost](http://boost.org).

Comment: I am using boost now for threading, regex, and other things. But their use of templates drive me nuts, particularly their graph API.

Comment: TMP definitely isn't for the faint of heart :).  It probably doesn't help that the error messages are generally as indecipherable as cuneiform :(.

Answer (score 0):

Options that might work for you.

1. Make `writeDataToFile` a function template.

   ```
   template <typename T> 
      void writeDataToFile(TileGrid<T> * grid, std::string fileName);
   ```

   In the implementation of this function, use another function template to write individual elements of the tile.

   ```
   template <typename T> 
      void writeTileElement(T const& tileElement, std::ostream& out);
   ```

   You can create overloaded versions of `writeTileElement` to take care of special handling of different types of objects.
2. Use a `TileGrid` of `ImageTile*` instead of `ImageFile`.

   ```
   void writeDataToFile(TileGrid<ImageStitching::ImageTile*> * grid, std::string fileName);
   ```